# How to check if a bin exists in an aerospike database using java?

Tags: java, database, aerospike

How to check if a bin exists in a set of an aerospike database?

For example I have a set named users{name, age, rollno}, how to check if rollno bin exists using java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set is just a tag on a record. (Metadata) - not a schema definition in Aerospike. Bins exist in a record. So record1 may have rollno and record2 may not. In fact same bin name can have different data type from record to record.

In other words, Aerospike has a "Record Level Schema".

Comment: so the only way to check if a record has a bin, is to retrieve it first and then check?

Comment: For a specific record, yes, you have to read it in the application. But you can also build a Secondary Index on a bin and find all records that match a particular value of the bin.